# '99 Honda accord sputtering when accelerating and stalling at idle

Tags: honda, fuel-system, accord, hesitation

My car is a '99 Honda Accord (V6). I have been putting mid-grade gas since I got it but I put in regular gas the other day and I believe that's when it started sputtering. It's getting worse now.

The sputtering happens when I accelerate, and it stalls. I got an oil change recently so there shouldn't be anything wrong with that.

What could be going on?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you got a bad batch of fuel and have some water in your fuel tank.

You can use a fuel additive with alcohol in order to get the water 'mixed in' with the gas.

You can also put the highest octane fuel in your car and try and drive through it, results may vary.

Your local auto parts store can recommend the additive they carry to get the water out of the fuel.

If this isn't helpful you have to begin troubleshooting the car.